# Soap Client consuming Rest Web Services

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

I am working on this project where the client only supports SOAP WSDL for consuming web services where as it supports rest for incoming calls. I need to Integrate this tool with another tool which is completely restful(has WADL). Is is possible for soap client to consume restful web services? If yes which tool will you all suggest?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Do you use the words "the client" to mean the same thing as "this tool" and "soap client"? If your answer is yes, then do I understand correctly, that this tool supports calling SOAP-based web services and your question is how you could let it call web services defined in WADL? Note, that REST is just an architectural style and that SOAP-based webservices can be RESTful as well.

Comment: Yes you can. Using jax-ws you can do it with the `Provider` and `Dispatch` APIs. You can even call a REST service using `HttpURLConnection`. After all, calling a REST endpoint is just making an HTTP request to a certain url. Here you have some examples: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Web-Services-SOA/RESTbasedWebServicesusingtheHTTPbindingandJAXWSProviderDispatch.htm , http://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-write-restful-web-services-with-jax-ws/ , https://www.subbu.org/blog/2006/08/jax-ws-for-restful-web-services

Answer (score 2):

**SOAP** defines a standard communication protocol (set of rules) specification for XML-based message exchange. SOAP uses different transport protocols, such as HTTP and SMTP. The standard protocol HTTP makes it easier for SOAP model to tunnel across firewalls and proxies without any modifications to the SOAP protocol.

**REST** describes a set of architectural principles by which data can be transmitted over a standardized interface (such as HTTP). REST does not contain an additional messaging layer and focuses on design rules for creating stateless services. A client can access the resource using the unique URI and a representation of the resource is returned. With each new resource representation, the client is said to transfer state. While accessing RESTful resources with HTTP protocol, the URL of the resource serves as the resource identifier and GET, PUT, DELETE, POST and HEAD are the standard HTTP operations to be performed on that resource.

It can be done via jQuery.

jQuery sample for the Language Identifier :

```
$.post('https://services.open.xerox.com/RestOp/LanguageIdentifier/GetLanguageForString', 
{'document' : 'This is a sample'}, function (data) {
  var res = 'Not found';
  if (data != null) {
    res = data;
  }
});
```

Further reading: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible for a soap client to consume restful services. There is no interoperability between them whatsoever.

Even if you could do this you should not. Use a tooling library and just create a rest client for your rest service.